# Get players name and image using Google Play Game Services

Tags: android, google-play-games

I have a game that is using *Google Play Game Services* and I'm storing players id in my database.

I know that for currently signed in player I can get name and image with:

```
String name = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(googleApiClient).getDisplayName();
Uri photo = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(googleApiClient).getIconImageUri();
```

but can I get them for a player who is not signed in if I know his *player id*?

I don't want to store players name and image in database since the player could change it in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this method.

> [`Game.Players.loadPlayer(GoogleApiClient apiClient, String playerId)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Players.html)
>
> Loads the profile for the requested player ID.